# How to find key value from response json string in ios?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json, ios7

I am using AFNetworking to get json data I have received this data using this code ...

```
 NSLog(@"Success: %@", [responseObject description]);
     NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
     NSString *products = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"d"];
     NSLog(@"pro %@",products);

     NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",products];
     NSData* data = [newString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

here we get successfully data and this is output of products is....

```
(
"{\"First\":\"TMT\",\"Second\":\"9a04f37d-8261-4898-94e7-0030b5aef3c1\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TRUS FOR PROSTATE\",\"Second\":\"4358a346-f69f-4e34-81ad-0657835eb69c\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TB PCR - Pus\",\"Second\":\"88370116-be77-4d9d-a170-08bd7ca1cc36\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TYPHIDOT IgG\",\"Second\":\"a14424a3-f1b1-4cde-9c8e-0bf214528fbf\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TB PCR - CSF\",\"Second\":\"ec2d08cd-d46c-48f9-b094-0c5789b47502\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TYPHIDOT (IgG \\u0026 IgM)\",\"Second\":\"592c4e58-7d03-49ab-a80e-0ca87dea8d14\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TLC,DLC\",\"Second\":\"fcbbde12-493a-4535-b895-0d5cb1db91e4\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TB PCR - BLOOD\",\"Second\":\"10288f38-45f5-433d-8d00-0deab0dbb08e\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TPHA\",\"Second\":\"d776f639-0eb7-4ab9-b72e-0e495915810c\"}",
"{\"First\":\"TOXOPLASMA IgG\",\"Second\":\"5975ecca-5f5a-4795-aadb-0fae3825b458\"}"
 )
```

but now I want to get key value of First from this string So I'm using below lines but I got output of jsonobjects is null. So please tell me how to get key value.

```
     NSError* error;
     id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
       NSLog(@"user id %@",jsonObjects);
```

Comment: Your deserialization probably isn't working because your quotation marks are escaped out using `\"`

Comment: this string is ajax format so can get data from ajax string format ?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not sure

Comment: What's the output of `responseObject`? Anyways, you may replace yours `\"` of your string with `"`, and convert it again into NSData an the usion `NSJSONSerialization`, but seems ugly.

Comment: What's "AJAX format"?  Looks like JSON to me, that has gone through some unnecessary escaping process.

Comment: you have to replace those \ (escape sequence) from your json